# Nginx, CakePHP: Error: Create the class Index.phpController below in file: App/Controller/Index.phpController.php

Tags: nginx, cakephp

I've config nginx 1.4 for running cakephp 2.6, but it can't work. For every page, for example http://my-app/ or http://my-app/admin it always return the error:
Error: Create the class Index.phpController below in file: App/Controller/Index.phpController.php

**my-app config:**

```
server {
    server_name  www.my-app;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://my-app$1 permanent;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name my-app;
        root   /usr/share/nginx/my-app/App/webroot;
        index index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/security;

        # Logging --
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/my-app.access.log;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/my-app.error.log notice;

        # Not found this on disk?
        # Feed to CakePHP for further processing!       
        location / {
            index  index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ \.php/ {
            include        fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }


        location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;
        #location = /404.html {
        #    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        #}

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }


        # Deny access to .htaccess files,
        # git & svn repositories, etc
        location ~ /(\.ht|\.git|\.svn) {
            deny  all;
        }
        # Compression. Reduces the amount of data that needs to be transferred over 
        # the network
        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 10240;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml;
        gzip_disable "MSIE [1-7]\.";
}
```

**/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;**

```
fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING        $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD      $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE        $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH      $content_length;

fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME     $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI     $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI        $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT       $document_root;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL     $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_script_name;

fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE     nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR     $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT     $remote_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR     $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT     $server_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME     $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS     200;
```